# How can a question get more upvotes than its number of views?

Tags: support, views, up-votes

As part of my waking up routine, I turn to [the questions page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions) and I see the [following](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144332/what-are-the-standards-of-tex-latex-coding-in-order-to-obtain-robust-packages):

[image: votes and views]

How can a question get more upvotes than views?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think (and [m0sa's terse comment](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3929/how-can-a-question-gets-more-upvotes-than-its-number-of-views/3930?noredirect=1#comment13317_3929) seems to back me up) that this happened because the question was migrated: the votes were migrated along with the question, but the view counter was reset.

Comment: This is indeed the probable reason; I suspected a possible problem on my end, but your explanation convinces me. Thanks.

Comment: @Jake, What happens to the reputation? Do you get rep on the new site for the migrated questions?

Comment: @Pacerier: I don't think so